# Homepage is very slow because of many images

Tags: php, html, css, ftp

I was making a website of one of my customers, when I was finished is uploaded the website to the web but some pages are very slow because of some images.
http://gthbouw.nl/Fotoboek/Outdoor.php
(this is page is the slowest)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>Timmerbedrijf GTH bouw uit Hattem voor al uw timmerwerken.</title>

        <!-- Meta -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Timmerwerken,timmerbedrijf,klussenbedrijf,interieurbouw,maatwerk,kasten,balie,keukens,krukken,tafels,restauratie,hattem,zwolle,wezep,oldebroek,wapenveld,heerde,staphorst,meppel, Timmerwerken,timmerbedrijf,klussenbedrijf,interieurbouw,maatwerk,suitewand,balie,keukens,kasten,tafels,restauratie,hattem,zwolle,wezep">
        <meta name="description" content="Timmerbedrijf GTH bouw voor al uw timmerwerken,kasten,meubels op maat,schuren,veranda&#39;s,kozijnen,suitewanden,houten vloeren. ">
        <meta name="author" content="GTH Bouw">
        <meta name="copyright" content="GTH bouw © Alle rechten voorbehouden.">
        <link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="_assets/magnifix-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="_assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/main.css" />
        <style>
            .cd-top {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 40px;
                width: 40px;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 40px;
                right: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
                overflow: hidden;
                text-indent: 100%;
                white-space: nowrap;
                background: #3498db url(https://codyhouse.co/demo/back-to-top/img/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
                visibility: hidden;
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
                -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
                transition: all 0.3s;
            }
            .cd-top.cd-is-visible {
                visibility: visible;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .cd-top.cd-fade-out {
                opacity: .5;
            }
            .no-touch .cd-top:hover {
                background-color: #e86256;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
              .cd-top {
                right: 20px;
                bottom: 20px;
              }
            }
            @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
              .cd-top {
                height: 60px;
                width: 60px;
                right: 30px;
                bottom: 30px;
              }
            }
            </style>

            <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="_assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="_assets/magnifix-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="_assets/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/BackToTop.js"></scripts?
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
                    if (this.hash !== "") {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var hash = this.hash;
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                    }, 800, function(){


                    window.location.hash = hash;
                    });
                    }
                    });
                });
            </script>
    </head>
This is my header maybe I need to change somtehing.

    <body>

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">
                        <div class="inner">

                            <!-- Header -->
                                <header id="header">
                                    <a href="../index.html" class="logo" ><strong>GTH bouw</strong> timmerwerken.</a>
                                    <ul class="icons">
                                        <li>Kijk voor meer recent werk ook op Twitter. </li>
                                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/gthbouw" target="_blank" style="font-size: 20px"class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </header>

                            <!-- Banner -->
                                <section id="banner">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <header>
                                            <h1>Outdoor
                                            </h1>
                                            <p>Laat u inspireren door GTH bouw.</p>
                                        </header>
                                        <p>Ook maak we veel dingen voor buitenhuis zoals bijvoorbeeld schuren, boomhutten & overkappingen. </p>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><a href="#ImageGallery" class="button special big">Kom verder</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="image object">
                                        <img  class="HeaderImg"src="../images/Outdoor.jpg" alt="" />
                                    </span>
                                </section>

                                <!-- ImageGallery -->
                                <section id="ImageGallery">
                                <header class="major">
                                    <a><h2>Fotoboek</h2></a>
                                </header>
                                                                    <p>*voor de beste ervaring op je smartphone of tablet kunt u uw mobiel kantelen om zo een betere indruk te krijgen van wat GTH bouw allemaal doet.</p>
```

This is my first part of the body. (this is probably not the issue)

```
                                    <div class="qt-photo-gallery-item qt-image-no-<?php echo $qt_counter; ?>">
                                        <a class="qt-photo-gallery-item-link" href="<?php echo $qt_file_path; ?>" >

                                            <div class="qt-photo-gallery-item-image-wrapper">

                                                <img src="<?php echo $qt_file_path; ?>" class="qt-photo-gallery-item-image" />

                                            </div>

                                        </a>
                                    </div>



                                    <?php

                                    if( $qt_counter == 5 ) {
                                        $qt_counter = 0;
                                    }

                                endif;

                            endwhile;


                            ?>
```

This is my PHP bit where it reads images from a specific directory and then it echo's the image to an Image gallery as you can see at the top of this question.

```
    <!-- Sidebar -->
                    <div id="sidebar">
                        <div class="inner">



                            <!-- Menu -->
                            <nav id="menu">
                                <header class="major">
                                    <a href="#sidebar"><h2>Menu</h2></a>
                                </header>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="../index.html" >Home</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="opener">Fotoboek</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="InterieurBouw.php" >Interieur bouw</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Outdoor.php" >Outdoor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Klantspecifiek.php" >Klantspecifiek</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Diversen.php" >Diversen</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="../contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>

                            <!-- Section -->
                                <section>
                                    <header class="major">
                                        <h2>Wat ik doe</h2>
                                    </header>
                                    <div class="mini-posts">
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="InterieurBouw.php" class="image"><img src="../images/InterieurBouw.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <p><b>Interieur bouw,</b></br>U kunt ons in huren om uw woonkamer, Keuken, Badkamer te maken en in te richten. Zo maken we bijvoorbeeld tafels, stoelen, kasten en nog veel meer.</p>
                                        </article>
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="Outdoor.php" class="image"><img src="../images/Outdoor.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <p><b>Outdoor,</b></br>Ook maken we veel dingen voor buitenhuis zoals bijvoorbeeld schuren, boomhutten & overkappingen. </p>
                                        </article>
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="Klantspecifiek.php" class="image"><img src="../images/Klantspecifiek.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <p><b>Klantspecifiek,</b></br>Natuurlijk doen wij ook veel projecten voor klanten die iets specifieks willen voor hun huis of winkel.</p>
                                        </article>
                                    </div>
                                </section>

                            <!-- Section -->
                                <section>
                                    <header class="major">
                                        <h2>Contact</h2>
                                    </header>
                                    <p>U kunt natuurlijk op vele verschillende mogelijkheden contact met mij opnemen. Wilt u vrijblijvend een afspraak maken of een offerte ontvangen? Neem dan contact met mij op door een mail te sturen of door gewoon even te bellen.</p>
                                    <ul class="contact">
                                        <li class="fa-envelope-o">info@gthbouw.nl</li>
                                        <li class="fa-phone">(Mob) 06 - 2281 7245</li>
                                        <li class="fa-home">Schipsweg 13 8051 KG<br />
                                        Hattem.</li>
                                        <li class="fa-map-marker">Locatie</li>
                                        <div  style="width: 100%; margin-top: 15px;"><iframe width="100%" height="300" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=100%&amp;height=600&amp;hl=en&amp;coord=52.4822692, 6.036609999999996&amp;q=Schipsweg%2013%208051%20KG%20Hattem.+(GTH)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div><br />
                                    </ul>
                                </section>

                            <!-- Footer -->
                                <footer id="footer">
                                    <p class="copyright">&copy; <a href="#wrapper">GTHbouw</a> Alle rechten voorbehouden.</p>
                                </footer>

                            <!-- Back to top -->
                                <a href="#0" class="cd-top">Top</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

This is the rest of my body and the other stuff

The images are compressed and about 0,4 mb or something. 
Can anyone help me making this webpage faster.

Comment: You are using 4000px picture as a thumbnail...

Comment: @Mehdi is there a way how i can make that smaller

Comment: Well.. by resizing the image. You can use some caching too.

Comment: Using a image cropper online or photoshop related software.

Comment: I use GIMP to reduce the size, but many things including Windows Paint will do it.

Comment: GIMP, Photoshop and an online cropper are all not good solutions... What if you dynamically add pictures? then you'd have to go and resize them manually every time. You can do that with PHP.

Comment: Image optimization...result: less kbs

Comment: @Mehdi I found something on the internet about adding pictures dinamically in PHP thnx for the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compress and resize your images.

Try this: https://imageresize.org/compress-images

and now you replace your old uncompressed images with compressed images.

Let us know the page load time after that. :)

Edit: As pointed out by @Mehdi If it's dynamic(Uploaded via PHP) you can use Imagick to resize and compress on upload.

Example for resize: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

Example for compress: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php

Comment: What if you dynamically add pictures? then you'd have to go and resize them manually every time. You can do that with PHP.

Comment: It worked but my customer don't want to do all that stuff manually. although thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer. You need not do it manually. you can use PHP to do the job when they are uploaded.
Also, please upvote/accept the answer if it worked. :)